# Connecting to mysql without default database and invalid credentials don't give error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create installing script for one of my webpages.
The process will be performed as follows: connect to MySQL, create database, create tables etc.

However, when I was doing some error handling during connect to MtSQL with empty database provided and with invalid username/password, there is no error in connection:

```
$connection = new mysqli( "localhost", "rootaaa", "", "" );
echo $connection->connect_errno;
```

And after I provided some default database, error message popped out:

```
$connection = new mysqli( "localhost", "rootaaa", "", "mysql" );
echo $connection->connect_errno;
```

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql' in ...t_postinstall.php on line 18

Looking at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php parameter dbname is defined as:

> **dbname**:
>   If provided will specify the default database to be used when performing queries.

So there is possibility to leave database empty.

Can someone explain me why do I get no error if i give invalid credentials?

I'm using PHP 5.6.3 and mySQL 5.6.21.

Comment: WHat explanation do you need?

Comment: I have edited question: why do i get no error if I provide invalid credentials

Comment: If the database name is not provided then no database is selected, only connection will be established.

Comment: but shouldn't be connection also invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have `rootaaa` user on your server, but the user has no rights to access to the `mysql` database.

MySQL allows to connect to the server without specifying a default database (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) of the c library for instance, which is wrapped by my msqli too). So if the user exists, you specified its credentials, but you don't specify the database, the user can connect to the server (it may still have some rights to do there something), and the connection won't produce you any error messages.

E.g:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
mysql> create user 'rootaaa';

mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='rootaaa';
+---------+------+----------+
| user    | host | password |
+---------+------+----------+
| rootaaa | %    |          |
+---------+------+----------+

$ mysql -u rootaaa test
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'rootaaa'@'%' to database 'test'

$ mysql -u rootaaa
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
```

If you grant the user access to the database...

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
mysql> grant all on test.* to 'rootaaa'@'%';

$ mysql -u rootaaa test
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
```

Comment: Actually there isn't user named rootaa. For sake of precisity I tried user with some random ascii characters, and got the same result. The problem is that if not registered user try to connect without specifying database you got no error. However, I didn't tried it from mysql prompt.